# What should I do when clarifying updates to a question invalidate my first answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

I wrote an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542385/number-format-exception-in-java-servlet) that was a little vague.

The question was then updated to provide enough information to give a proper answer, and the actual solution is far different from the answer I had initially given.

Should I edit my answer or add a new one? The additional information in the question completely invalidates my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Always edit your existing answer**, never post a second answer.

It's your choice whether you think your original answer is worth saving and you want to just append the new answer to the end, or if you want to erase the whole thing and start over.

Comment: Sometimes deleting it and posting a new one might also be a good choice. I would do that if the answer got more than one or two downvotes due to it not fitting anymore due to the edit.